# Can I avoid this linq query redundancy?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

My code :

```
var myList = xDoc.Descendants("localita").Select(n => new
{
    ID = n.Element("id").Value.ToString(),
    Localita = n.Element("nome").Value.ToString(),
    Lat = n.Element("lat").Value.ToString(),
    Lng = n.Element("lon").Value.ToString(),
    MeteoOggi = new MeteoGiorno()
    {
        Min = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("temp_perc").Value.ToString(),
        Max = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("temp").Value.ToString(),
        DescrizioneTempo = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("desc_tempo").Value.ToString(),
        Precipitazioni = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("prec").Value.ToString(),
        VentoDirezione = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("v_dir").Value.ToString(),
        VentoIntensita = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("v_int").Value.ToString(),
        Pressione = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("press").Value.ToString(),
        ZeroTermico = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("zerot").Value.ToString(),
        Immagine = n.Descendants("previsione").First().Element("id_tempo").Value.ToString()
    }
});
```

but as you can see, that `n.Descendants("previsione").First()` is "searched" each time when I set the values for the Class `MeteoGiorno`. Can I put a sort of reference to that node in my example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can, just change the `Select`:

```
var myList = xDoc.Descendants("localita").Select(n => {
   var previsione = n.Descendants("previsione").First();

   return new {
      ID = n.Element("id").Value.ToString(),
      ....
      MeteoOggi = new MeteoGiorno()
      {
          Min = previsione.Element("temp_perc").Value.ToString(),
          Max = previsione.Element("temp").Value.ToString(),
          ....
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I have to keep also the first block of data, which come from `n` :O

Comment: @markzzz - there's no difference.. I just didnt copy out *all* of your code. See update - is that clearer?

Comment: That's just perfect! Thank you! Linq is so powerful!